# How to use depth camera in Unity HDRP?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use depth camera in HDRP, but I haven't found any relevant information or examples. Here is an example, but it's not HDRP. How can I implement it.
https://github.com/jabrail-chumakov/Unity-Depth-Camera-Implementation